# Symfony4 show latest Posts in Sidebar

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I want to display the last x Posts in a sidebar.

So currently i have the following in my base.twig:

```
{% block sidebar %}
    {% for page in lastPages %}
        <a href="{{ path('page_show', {'slug': page.slug}) }}">{{ page.title }}</a> <br>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

In my Controller i use the repository to get the last posts:

```
$lastPages = $pageRepository->getLastPages();
```

And after that, i render the view

```
return $this->render('page/index.html.twig', ['lastPages' => $lastPages, .....]);
```

But now i want to use this functionallity in every controller.

i could create a method in the `AbstractController` like

```
function getLatestPosts(PageRepository $pageRepository): array
{
    $pageRepository->getLastPages();
}
```

and after this render the view:

```
return $this->render('page/index.html.twig', ['lastPages' => $this->getLatestPosts($repository), .....]);
```

But, uh.

Is there something like a global Filter/Function e.g.? I didn't find a good way to make this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your template you can render the controller which is responsible for the sidebar like this:

```
{{ render(controller('App\\Default::renderSidebar')) }}
```

Read more about it here
https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/embedding_controllers.html